# How to break sections in Overleaf Latex

Tags: page-breaking

I have separated my thesis in several chapters. In one chapter I have two sections (4.1 and 4.2). In 4.1 section I have my text and 5 figures related to its content. However, the text of 4.2 section starts before the figures of the first section, having the text of both sections together and the rest of the figures of both sections after that. How is it possible to break these sections? 
I have created different files for each section (`chapter041` and `chapter042`) and I have inserted these commands in my `main.tex`:

```
\chapter{Material and Methods}
\input{chapters/chapter041}
\input{chapters/chapter042}
```

Comment: `\clearpage` before the second `\input` would stop floats going past

Comment: `\input` acts as if the contents of that file were right there.  Since floats are allowed to float around to a later page, they do so without regard to the `\input`.  As @ DavidCarlisle points out, `\clearpage` forces the floats to print, and not float any later.

Comment: `\include{}` instead of `\input{}` will start a new page for you automatically. It also can help with building only one chapter at a time (combined with `\includeonly{}`.

Comment: Search  also questions including  `\FloatBarrier`

Comment: Thank you for your comments! \clearpage worked like I wanted! Thank you!